# Accessing arguments in a different class

Tags: java

I am wondering how do you access an argument created in a different class?

What I have:

```
public class Card {         
    private final int cardNumber;
    private String cardName;
    private final String cardOwner;
    private final boolean isCredit; 
    private double balance;

    public Card(int cardNumber, String cardName, String cardOwner, boolean isCredit, double balance) {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        this.cardName = cardName;
        this.cardOwner = cardOwner;         
        ...
}
```

I want to access the argument `cardOwner` in the following way:

```
public void add(Card[] newCards) {                  
        if (cardOwner == owner) {
            ...    
        }
}
```

but I am not sure on how to go about doing that?

Comment: What class is `add` in?

Comment: Iterate through the ```newCards``` array and use a getter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access arguments outside the method they're in. Full stop.

What you can do is access the fields (which in your code have the same name as the constructor arguments. I recommend not giving different things the same name until you understand them well).

If you want to access the field `cardOwner` from inside the `Card` class, you can just use its name.

If you want to access the field `cardOwner` from *outside* the `Card` class, you will first need to decide *which* card you want to get the owner of. If you have a reference to a card (call it `card`), then you can use `card.cardOwner` to get that card's owner.

*However*, `private` members (fields/methods/constructors) can only be accessed from within the same class (that is the entire point of `private`). You could either make the field `public` instead, or add another way to access the field's value, such as a small `public` method:

```
public String getCardOwner() {
    return cardOwner;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the getter you added to access it but how do I access it from the different class?

Comment: @Luffy: `card.getCardOwner()` if `card` is a reference to a Card (it doesn't actually have to be called `card`)

Comment: @Luffy then you don't have a reference to a card. Which card do you want to get the owner of?

Comment: @Luffy when you call a constructor (using `new`), just like when you call a method, you have to pass it the actual values. You don't write `int addOne(int x) {return x+1;}` and then call it with `System.out.println(addOne(int x));` - you would write `System.out.println(addOne(5));`, or `System.out.println(addOne(someNumber));` where `someNumber` is an `int` variable.. Similarly for constructors, the only difference being they have `new` in front, and they create new objects, and they don't have return types.

Comment: But the parameters are still not defined yet, so there are no values to assign them with.

Comment: Well what values do you want them to have? The computer can't magically decide who owns the card; you have to say who owns the card. (And its number, and whether it's a credit card, and the name on it, and its balance)

Comment: I should say, in case you haven't realised it yet, that your current code structure makes it impossible to create a card without setting its name, number, owner, isCredit and balance at the same time. (This is usually considered a good thing since it helps stop you making mistakes, like having a card with no name)

Comment: The values for the parameters will be defined through scanners. The user will input them in.

Comment: @Luffy well then you have to read them before you create the card, or change how the `Card` class is defined so that you can create a card without a name/number/isCredit/owner/balance (and then set them later).

Comment: This is more difficult than I thought, but I will accept your answer and try to find a way to make it work. Thank you for all your help!